# How to implement system/light/dark theme changing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, themes

My goal is to have an app where:

the theme property is global and can be changed from a Settings screen, like this:

the user can set the system, light or dark theme.

Any suggestion? Should I add a property to the theme object, e.g. a systemDefault boolean, to tell whether the app should consider/ignore the system default?

Comment: usage of `styled-component` together with the proposed `ThemeProvider` should do the trick: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced. Create an observed variable that set's the theme in the provider.